# How to track and display when a row is updated with angularJS/MVC WEB api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a SPA with a grid of people. As changes are made to a person I want a visual indicator so something like this within the ng-repeat

```
 <span ng-show="show_check()"><i class="icon-ok"></i></span>
```

So do I

1. Extend the place model with an additional Boolean field to track this ? But if I do this I need to stop the Data Model edmx file from overwriting the custom field. Also, I don't want this info saved to the server anyways.. I just want to show what rows have been edited purely on the client side
2. Create a array in javascript and for each row in ng-repeat do I check the current row ID vs the collection of IDs in the array (The array containing the items already updated)

Or is there a better way?  I am new to angular and do not want to do things the hard way..

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely clear of what you are asking, the question seems to be mixing client concepts with server logic (EDMX?). But if you are using a form for editing, there is a way to detect if the form is dirty.

See the form directive:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

HTH

Comment: I meant for a grid of data where each row was an editable item.. not for a form of a specific row..  So theres grid of items and I want a nice green checkbox to appear next to the row after the user has updated it... so anyways.. I guess solution #2 is the best way.. I wasn't sure if angular had anything that made this even easier